# Count frequencies within a scope of time per day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_id': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3],
    'order_time': ['2010-01-01 01:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:05:00' , '2010-01-01 01:24:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:00', '2010-01-01 01:33:00', '2010-01-01 01:34:00', '2010-01-01 01:35:00', '2010-01-01 01:37:00', '2010-01-01 01:38:00', '2010-01-13 05:52:00', '2010-01-13 05:53:00', '2010-01-13 05:54:00', '2010-01-13 05:58:00', '2010-01-13 06:04:00', '2010-01-13 06:14:00', '2010-01-13 06:25:00', '2010-01-13 06:024:00', '2010-01-13 06:26:00', '2010-01-13 06:27:00']
})
```

I would like to count the number of orders made per customer per day **within the very first 30 (and 40) minutes since the first order that day**. "The first order" here refers to the first order made by the first customer, not to be counted per customer separately.

The expected output:

[image: please see the photo here]

For instance,

- In "Scope_30_min", `Customer_id = 1` ordered 2 times within the 30 minutes scope. All orders beyond the scope were not counted.
- In "Scope_40_min", `Customer_id = 1` ordered 3 times within the 40 minutes scope (it is the total of the scope_30_min=2 + 1 beyond the 30 minutes).

Comment: I have forgot to add something that defines the beginning of the scope, let us say starting from "2010-01-01 01:01:00" and then the calculation of scope 30 minutes would be 01:31:00 something like that.

Comment: Ambiguous descriptions. The statement "In `Scope_30_min` the customer of `id = 1` ordered `2` times and `0` time beyond the 30 minutes scope of time" is literally false. Please explain what defines the matching period (the beginning time and the end time respectively) for each record.

Comment: Well, if you search within 30 minutes scope starting from ```2010-01-01 01:01:00``` and ending at ```2010-01-01 01:31:00``` you will see the ```id = 1``` odered 2 times within 30 minutes and for the ```Scope_30_min``` beyond ```2010-01-01 01:31:00``` the  ```id = 1``` ordered 0 time dated at ```2010-01-01 01:33:00```. On the contrary if you switch to the ```Scope_40_min``` you will find that ```id = 1``` ordered 3 times in total within 40 minutes, does that make sense?

Comment: Still ambiguous. If the same logic is applied to `id=2`, then 01:34:00 is within 30 minutes of 01:05:00. Why it did not count?

Comment: right, however, we set the start of the scope, e.g. ```2010-01-01 01:01:00``` which applies to all users in the same day, and we pick the  ```2010-01-01 05:52:00``` as a start for the next day_id. Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Logic

1. Get the order date for later groupby's.
2. Use `.groupby().transform("first")` to obtain the first `order_time` per order date, from which the time elapsed since the first order can be derived.
3. Get the total order count per order date per customer (within the time difference computed previously) and merge the result back into `df`.

### Data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer_id': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3],
    'order_time': ['2010-01-01 01:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:05:00' , '2010-01-01 01:24:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:00', '2010-01-01 01:33:00', '2010-01-01 01:34:00', '2010-01-01 01:35:00', '2010-01-01 01:37:00', '2010-01-01 01:38:00', '2010-01-13 05:52:00', '2010-01-13 05:53:00', '2010-01-13 05:54:00', '2010-01-13 05:58:00', '2010-01-13 06:04:00', '2010-01-13 06:14:00', '2010-01-13 06:25:00', '2010-01-13 06:024:00', '2010-01-13 06:26:00', '2010-01-13 06:27:00']
})

# work on dates
df['order_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['order_time'])

# sort in chronological order
# df.sort_values("order_time", inplace=True)
```

### Code

Scope window = 30mins is shown here.

```
# compute time difference
df["order_date"] = df["order_time"].dt.date
df["t_diff"] = df["order_time"] - df.groupby("order_date")["order_time"].transform("first")

# compute the order count column
m = 30
sr_count = df[df["t_diff"].le(pd.Timedelta(minutes=m))].groupby(["Customer_id", "order_date"]).size()
sr_count.name = f"Scope_{m}_min"
# put the above result back back
df = df.merge(sr_count, how="left", on=["Customer_id", "order_date"], suffixes=("", "_y"))
# set out-of-range entries to zero
df.loc[df["t_diff"].gt(pd.Timedelta(minutes=m)), f"Scope_{m}_min"] = 0
```

### Result

```
print(df)

    Customer_id          order_time  order_date          t_diff  Scope_30_min
0             1 2010-01-01 01:01:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:00:00           2.0
1             2 2010-01-01 01:05:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:04:00           2.0
2             1 2010-01-01 01:24:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:23:00           2.0
3             2 2010-01-01 01:27:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:26:00           2.0
4             1 2010-01-01 01:33:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:32:00           0.0
5             2 2010-01-01 01:34:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:33:00           0.0
6             3 2010-01-01 01:35:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:34:00           0.0
7             4 2010-01-01 01:37:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:36:00           0.0
8             4 2010-01-01 01:38:00  2010-01-01 0 days 00:37:00           0.0
9             1 2010-01-13 05:52:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:00:00           2.0
10            2 2010-01-13 05:53:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:01:00           2.0
11            1 2010-01-13 05:54:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:02:00           2.0
12            2 2010-01-13 05:58:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:06:00           2.0
13            3 2010-01-13 06:04:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:12:00           1.0
14            4 2010-01-13 06:14:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:22:00           1.0
15            4 2010-01-13 06:25:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:33:00           0.0
16            2 2010-01-13 06:24:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:32:00           0.0
17            1 2010-01-13 06:26:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:34:00           0.0
18            3 2010-01-13 06:27:00  2010-01-13 0 days 00:35:00           0.0
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you very much for your answer. It is really helpful and it works for me now. Jsut another question. If would change the srtart time we pick for each day, so that I would like to pick each value in row as a start and look for frequency in this period of time. For example: ```2010-01-01 01:01:00``` would be picked as a start date for the nex 30 minutes, means within ```2010-01-01 01:31:00``` and I would to take all dates sequentially so the next "start" is the next oreder time ```2010-01-01 01:05:00``` and the scope of 30 minutes would be ```2010-01-01 01:35:00``` and so forth

Comment: "Another question" should be posted as another question. And I cannot understand what is your expected output from your description above. Please GIVE CONCRETE RULES AND SAMPLE OUTPUT in your post.